# What is the name of this flower?

Tags: species-identification, flowers

[image: flower.]

This is from Bangladesh though I am not sure it's native here

Comment: Seems *Plumeria* , of Apocynaceae. Tree?  Add image of leaves. Give better description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google](https://www.google.co.in/imghp) image search gave me answer as "[Plumeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumeria)"

Comment: I never knew that was possible with Google Images. +1 :D

Comment: Google has lot of such very less known functions :P

Comment: Not all plants could be so easily identified with google image (till). Maybe this flower's simple shape and color made that easier.

Answer (score 1):

Also known as FrangiPani in Africa. Has lovely sweet scent, I have a white and pink tree in my garden, they are about 8 ft tall. Doesn't like frost

Answer (score 1):

[White Frangipani](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A0+%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AA&oq=%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A0+%E0%A6%97%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AA): Plumeria Spp. In Bengali: কাঠ গোলাপ (pronounced Kath Golap). Straight translation is wood rose or pink and they do have rose color.